# Query with include and exclude values

Tags: sql, hana

I am trying to query a table and get from it some values based on another table that have include and exclude criteria.

I have the main table like this:

```
ColA
600000
675100
123000
```

And the criteria table like this:

```
Value | Type
6%    | I
67%   | E
```

where `%` acts as a wild card.

The resulting table should be:

```
ColA
600000
```

i have already made it to get the right result like this:

```
select * 
    from main
    inner join criteria inc
        on ColA like inc.value
        and inc.type = 'I'
    left outer join criteria exc
        on ColA like exc.value
        and exc.type = 'E'
    where exc.value is null
    ;
```

But I was hoping I could get it without having to query the criteria table twice since there is some calculation involved in the creation of it.

I guess it is just a matter of possible performance improvement, but I see no harm in asking the community!

Thank you all!

**EDIT:**

As mentioned on the comments, I managed to get the criteria table into a range. I accomplished that using this query (expecting a 10 digits number):

```
select  case
            when type = 'I'
                then low
            when type = 'E'
                then low_1
        end as low,
        case
            when lead(type) over (order by low asc) = 'E'
                then case
                    when type = 'I' and high < lead(low) over (order by low asc)
                        then high
                    else lead(high_1) over (order by low asc) end
            when type = 'I'
                then high
            else
                max_high
        end as high
    from (
        select  *,
                rpad(digits,10,9) as high,
                rpad(digits+1,10,0) as low_1,
                rpad(digits-1,10,9) as high_1
            from (
                select  main.*,
                        max( for_max_high ) as max_high
                    from (
                        select  type,
                                replace(value,'%','') as digits,
                                rpad(replace(value,'%',''),10,0) as low
                            from criteria
                        ) main
                    left outer join (
                        select  replace(value,'%','') as digits,
                                rpad(replace(value,'%',''),10,9) as for_max_high
                            from criteria
                            where type = 'I'
                    ) for_max
                        on  main.low > rpad(for_max.digits,10,0)
                        and main.type = 'E'
                    group by type, main.digits, low
            )
    )
;
```

I hope this could be of some use to someone!

Answer (score 1):

In most of the database you can use a WITH clause. Does HANA support WITH clauses/ CTE?

See example below. The process gets the data once and uses it as many time as you like. This will improve performance.

```
WITH v_criteria AS
(
 SELECT type, value 
   FROM criteria 
  WHERE type IN ('I', 'E') 
)
select * 
    from main
    inner join v_criteria inc
        on ColA like inc.value
        and inc.type = 'I'
    left outer join v_criteria exc
        on ColA like exc.value
        and exc.type = 'E'
    where exc.value is null
    ;
```

Comment: Didn't know about the WITH clause. Yes it improved the performance, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While SAP HANA does support common table expressions (CTE, the `WITH` clause) it does not help the performance of the query.

Using `EXPLAIN PLAN` you can see that HANA uses the exact same execution plan for both mentioned ways of writing your query.

```
OPERATOR_NAME                       OPERATOR_DETAILS                                    TABLE_NAME
ROW SEARCH                          MAIN.COLA, INC.TYPE, INC.VALUE, INC.TYPE, INC.VALUE ?
  FILTER                            INC.VALUE IS NULL                                   ?
    NESTED LOOP JOIN (LEFT OUTER)   JOIN CONDITION: MAIN.COLA LIKE INC.VALUE            ?
      NESTED LOOP JOIN              JOIN CONDITION: MAIN.COLA LIKE INC.VALUE            ?
        COLUMN SEARCH               MAIN.COLA                                           ?
          COLUMN TABLE                                                                  MAIN
        COLUMN SEARCH               INC.VALUE, INC.TYPE                                 ?
          COLUMN TABLE              FILTER CONDITION: INC.TYPE = 'I'                    CRITERIA
      COLUMN SEARCH                 INC.VALUE, INC.TYPE                                 ?
        COLUMN TABLE                FILTER CONDITION: INC.TYPE = 'E'                    CRITERIA
```

Important to observe with this plan is that it uses two nested joins and both of the joins are `NESTED LOOP JOINS`.
For the minimal data set provided, this does not hurt but simply extending the table contents to 100.000 records (`main`) and 200.000 records (`criteria`) will send your database into a looong CPU-time feast.

Effectively the system has to run a `LIKE` comparison for every single iteration in the `NL` joins.
Depending on the data this can feed n*m records back into the outer loop, which in turn could also hit m matches

**n** x **m** x **m** `LIKE` comparisons =>  **O(n^3)**

Alternatively, you could use the following, set-based query:

```
/* include these */
    select 
          main.cola
    from 
                 main 
     inner join criteria cr_in
     on main.ColA like cr_in.value
     and cr_in.type = 'I'
MINUS
 /* exlude these */  
    select 
          main.cola
    from 
                 main 
     inner join criteria cr_in
     on main.ColA like cr_in.value
     and cr_in.type = 'E';
```

This leads to the following execution plan:

```
OPERATOR_NAME               OPERATOR_DETAILS                                           TABLE_NAME
ROW SEARCH                  MAIN.COLA                                                  ?
  DISTINCT                  GROUPING: MAIN.COLA                                        ?
    HASH JOIN (ANTI SEMI)   HASH BUILD: RIGHT, JOIN CONDITION: MAIN.COLA = MAIN.COLA   ?
      NESTED LOOP JOIN      JOIN CONDITION: MAIN.COLA LIKE CR_IN.VALUE                 ?
        COLUMN SEARCH       MAIN.COLA                                                  ?
          COLUMN TABLE                                                                 MAIN
        COLUMN SEARCH       CR_IN.VALUE                                                ?
          COLUMN TABLE      FILTER CONDITION: CR_IN.TYPE = 'I'                         CRITERIA
      NESTED LOOP JOIN      JOIN CONDITION: MAIN.COLA LIKE CR_IN.VALUE                 ?
        COLUMN SEARCH       MAIN.COLA                                                  ?
          COLUMN TABLE                                                                 MAIN
        COLUMN SEARCH       CR_IN.VALUE                                                ?
          COLUMN TABLE      FILTER CONDITION: CR_IN.TYPE = 'E'                         CRITERIA
```

Obviously, the two `NESTED LOOP JOINS` are still present but are not nested into one another. The combining `HASH JOIN` works one the result sets of the two `NESTED LOOP` joins with a single run over each.

Here we end up with an upper runtime limit of

- 2 x (n x m) (for the two `NESTED LOOP JOINS`)
- 2 * m  (for the `HASH JOIN`)

=> **O(n^2)**

This is better than before (and the two `NL`s are executed in parallel, as well), but still not really good.
Especially with large sets in `criteria` you want to look for a better solution.

One option, if you stay with the current design approach, would be to check for a potential shorter condition when new conditions are inserted and save them in an additional column.

Depending on the kind of criteria maintenance operations you want to support, this task can become quite elaborate (e.g. removing the shortest condition so far means a new shortest condition need to be found and the saved references need to be updated.

In total: be rather careful with the "dynamic" `LIKE` operator in join conditions.

Comment: Thank you @Lars. So the performance improvement was sheer luck? I had thought of the solution to use the `MINUS` operator but the problem is that what I am showing as `main` table is really a set of queries, not a single table. Will it still be better to go with that approach? Or should I try a Table Function or a Calculation View?

Comment: There’s no way to make assumptions about the execution plan over views when the view definition is not known; one has to check the final query with `EXPLAIN PLAN` for that. As mentioned, this whole design doesn’t allow for good performance, **as soon as there is more data**, especially more data on the criteria side. If you somehow ensure that there is only a small set of conditions, you might be fine with either approach.

Comment: My main problem is that the criteria table is built from a string that comes as an input parameter. I am now transforming this into a range table. When I join them together I made it to a single `NESTED LOOP JOIN` because I am now using `BETWEEN` only on the ranges I need. Still, would there be a bettter way?